# How to search string with strstr but with a key word that was not assigned by the user

Tags: c

This is the code

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr;
    char c_id[50];
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int choices;
    char* pos;
    int customer_id;
    printf("Enter customer ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &customer_id);
    sprintf(c_id, "%d", customer_id);
    fptr = fopen("servicestest.txt", "r");
    printf("\n1. Check for unpaid\n2. Check for paid\n");
    scanf("%d", &choices);
    switch (choices)
    {
    case 1:
        while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr)) != 0)
        {
            pos = strstr(str, "Not");

            if (pos == 1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", str);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr)) != 0)
        {
            pos = strstr(str, "Not");
            if (pos =! 1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", str);
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Was planning to check a line with not and print them how to do that? Why is it not printing anything when I inputted "1" as choices

I wanted to assign

```
char ch[50];
ch[1] = "Not";
```

but when i tried the `strstr (str, ch[1])` it caused an error

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you think `char ch[1] = "Not";` should do?

Comment: `if (pos =! 1)` typo: `if (pos != 1)`

Comment: `strstr` does not return an index, or a boolean. Please refer to the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=vs-2019)! *"Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `strSearch` in `str`, or `NULL` if `strSearch` does not appear in `str`."*

Answer (score 0):

1. check the return value of `fopen`:

```
if(!fptr) {
   return -1;
}
```

2. You try to compare between a pointer and `int` value.

```
if (pos == 1)
// and
if (pos =! 1) // even you can compare, it should be if (pos != 1)
```

If you want to calculate the position of substring `"Not"`, you can do as:

```
pos = strstr(str, "Not");
if(pos) {
   int pos_substring = (int) (str-pos);
   // from here you can compare the position of substring with an `int` value.
   if (pos_substring == 1) {/*do something*/}
   eles {/*do something*/}

}
```

3. When you try the code:

```
char ch[50];
char ch[1] = "Not"; // string "Not" need at least 4 bytes (3 bytes for 'N', 'o' and 't', 1 bytes for null character)
```

It should change to:

```
char ch[50] = "Not";
// or
char ch[] = "Not";
// or
const char *ch = "Not" // be attention with the string literal
```

Then when you want to apply to `strstr` function:

```
strstr (str, ch); // use ch instead of ch[1]
```

If you want to use something like `strstr (str, ch[1])`, you can use the 2D array of characters:

```
char ch[50][50] = {/*init the string here or later as you want*/}; // this 2D array contents of maximum 50 strings, each string length ups to 49.
strstr (str, ch[0]);
strstr (str, ch[1]);
strstr (str, ch[2]);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Why is it not printing anything when I inputted `1` as choices*

`char ch[1] = "Not";` is problematic, and invokes [undefined behavior (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

The string literal `"Not"` has 4 characters:  `|N|o|t|\0|`

The statement `char ch[1];` creates space for only one character, accessible in the zeroth element: `ch[0]`.

This causes the statement `strstr (str, ch[1])` to also invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since `ch[1]` does not exist, only 1 element exists - `ch[0]`.

The fix for this is to always provide enough space for the content needed.  These are valid way to create `ch` with enough space:

```
char ch[50] = "Not";//char array of 50 initialized to "Not"
char ch[4] = "Not";//char array of 4 initialized to "Not"
char ch[] = "Not";//char array of 4 initialized to "Not" (implicitly sized)
char *ch = "Not";//char * initialized to same string literal but not editable.
```

Using any of these will work with as shown in your code segment:

```
pos = strstr(str, "Not");
```

But usage of the result `pos` is to evaluate its contents as a pointer, not as an integer:

```
pos = strstr(str, "Not");
//if (pos =! 1)//wrong - pos is a pointer
// if (pos =! NULL)//ok - test for non-NULL
if (pos)//ok - implicit test for non-NULL
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```